# React page do not refresh as i change my app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npx

I am new to react as today is my day 2, I create react app using "npx create-react-app" bt when I make changes in the file like app.js. it does not reflect on the page, even I tried to refresh the page by going in the browser and refresh it, that also not working ( my node version is 16.13.1 and npm is 8.1.2)

```
  import logo from "./logo.svg";
  import "./App.css";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>
                    Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
                </p>
                <a
                    className="App-link"
                    href="https://reactjs.org"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                    Learn React is again not working with nik
                </a>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

 

package.json 
{
  "name": "hy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and I'm currently using windows 11

Comment: have you saved the changes?

Comment: Also, can you check if you are making the changes in correct workspace and not in a different one.

Comment: yup i make changes and save but nothing happen

Comment: Please add the code here instead of screenshots, provide us with info of your OS, this issue is too unclear to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've saved your changes. I see you are using vs code, you can enable auto save by pressing `ctrl` & `,` and searching for auto save. I recommend setting it to `onFocusChange`.

Also as @Mahipal mentioned in the comments, make sure you are making the changes in the correct workspace.